# My toFixed(); isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tofixed

I have the following JS here...

```
$(function($) {
    $('#CourseMenu select').change(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('#CourseMenu select').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });

     $('#total_potential').html(Math.min(sum,72).toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

...but the toFixed(); isn't working properly. It's not giving me the two decimal places after the whole number.

Is there something else I should add?

I've updated it to reflect @bfavaretto suggestion... but it's only returning values of .00

I have my values set to .67, 1.33, 2.67, and so forth.

Comment: .toFixed converts your number to a string. you are then not doing anything with the variable you saved it in `fixed`

Comment: You're not doing anything with `fixed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that when you are doing:

```
sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
```

It is changing the type. You should make the `toFixed` call at the end of the function.

**EDIT**

To address further questions by the OP.

@webfrogs if you are ending up with a result of .00 I would make two guesses as to things that could be going wrong in your code. (1) you are using `parseInt` which is then giving you a value of 0 for things like .67 (not sure if this is what you want) and (2) the variable `sum` might not be in the same scope, you could ensure the right variable is being used by passing the context explicitly. i.e.

```
$('#CourseMenu select').each(function(idx, elm) {
        sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
    }).bind(this);
```

Comment: I changed parseInt to parseFloat and it's working the way I want. the .67, etc is what I'm looking for, too... Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to apply `toFixed` right before printing the value, not at the start:

```
$('#total_potential').html(Math.min(sum,72).toFixed(2));
```

That's because `toFixed` doesn't restrict the number of decimal places on a number variable, it's just a formatting function that takes a number and returns a string with that number formatted with so many decimal places. So it's supposed to be used for output only.

Comment: I have my values set to .67, 1.33, 2.67, and so forth. But it's only returning values of .00 Why is that?